# Is "have traveled...twice" grammatical

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following usage of "have traveled ...twice" grammatical?

> I **have traveled** to Seattle **twice**.

Comment: @SovereignSun You mention you would use Simple Present - but twice is happened in past? Why Simple Present is correct here?

Comment: Past Simple I wanted to say. Surely Perfect sounds okay too.

Comment: It's grammatical. Meanwhile, "I have been to Seattle twice" is both grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang That's an interesting point but you can't say that one is more grammatically correct than the others without a context here.**travel** shows the process and not the fact while **I have been** shows a completed trip. I would personally use this construction too but why not **I travelled to Seattle twice**?

Answer (score 1):

> I **have traveled** to Seattle **twice**.

Yes, it is correct.

> I've **been** to Seattle twice.

This may be better and more common, and it also implies the traveling.